# How to set the name tag in a ngFor* loop dynamically?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dynamic, ngfor

I'm trying to set the name tag dynamically with values from a `ngFor` loop. It's no problem to assign a value to the id tag, but for the name tag it does not work.

```
<table class="compactTable">
  <tr *ngFor="let s of ps.State; let i = index;" >
    <td class="alignRight" width="15%">
        <input type="text" id ="{{i}}" (change)="check($event)" name ="{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="s.ZBez"> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The `$event`, which I pass `onChange` to the `check()` function has an `id` equal to `i`, but `name` is always an empty string. Why are they different and how can I set the `name` dynamically?

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. It's supposed to work fine. Can you provide a demo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use it like `[attr.ATTR_NAME]` and without double braces.

```
<input type="text" [attr.id]="i" (change)="check($event)" [attr.name]="i" [(ngModel)]="s.ZBez">
```

You can check this official docs about template syntax for more info:

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

**Update**

As @ConnorsFan stated in the comment, property binding should work as well. I created a stackblitz project with all possibilities. Please check it out:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckp8fz

Comment: Why does he "need" to use attribute binding? Property binding should work also, no?

Comment: Actually you are right. "Need" is not the correct word. I edited the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can try `[name]="i"`

```
<input type="text" id ="{{i}}" (change)="check($event)" [name]="i" [(ngModel)]="s.ZBez">
```

**EDIT:** For id you can try same `[attr.id]="i"`